# How can I complete an edit with the right arrow key in a Kendo grid cell?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, cell, edit, arrow-keys

When a Kendo grid cell is open for editing, what is the best way to close the cell (and move to the next cell) with the right arrow key?

Comment: This isn't user-friendly, the user will not be able to navigate through the text with the right arrow. Unless you make this happen when the cursor is at the end of the text content, but this still isn't the default behaviour. This is the behaviour of the tab key.

Comment: Yes sir I know that. But the requirements are asking for this as well. Thank you for your comments. Alan Painter

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the following snippet. It is a simple way for doing what you want:

```
// Bind any keyup interaction on the grid
$("#grid").on("keyup", "input", function(e)
{
    // Right arrow keyCode
    if (e.keyCode == 39)
    {
        // Ends current field edition.
        // Kendo docs says that editCell method:
        // "Switches the specified table cell in edit mode" 
        // but that doesn't happens and the current cell keeps on edit mode.
        var td = $(e.target)
                     .trigger("blur"); 

        // Find next field
        td = td.closest("td").next();

        // If no cell was found, look for the next row
        if (td.length == 0)
        {
            td = $(e.target).closest("tr").next().find("td:first");
        }

        // As ways happens on kendo, a little (ugly)workaround 
        // for calling editCell, because calling without 
        // the timer doesn't seem to work.
        window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            grid.editCell(td);
        }, 1);
    }
});
```

I don't know why but I could not save a Fiddle for that, I got 500 Internal error. Anyway it seems to achieve what you need. The grid needs to be in edit mode `incell`.